# Matrix proof: product of two symmetric matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I've been asked to prove or disprove the following:

Given $A,B$ $n$-ordered square matrices:

If $A$ and $B$ are symmetric and all of the elements in both of their main diagonals are equal to $1$, then $AB$ is also symmetric.

I realize it's a rather basic proof but it's got me stumped. The things I've tried so far are:

- Expressing the elements of $AB$ using sigma notation: $[AB]_{ij} = \sum\limits_{k=1}^n(A_{ik}\cdot B_{kj})$ and trying to show that  $[AB]_{ij} = [AB]_{ji}$ which I think would probably be the ideal way to do it but I somehow found myself not really being able to articulate why that's true.
- Create some general $A$ and $B$:

$$
A=
\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
1&a_{1_2}&a_{1_3}&\dots&a_{1_n}\\
a_{1_2}&1&a_{2,3}&\dots&a_{2_n}\\
a_{1_3}&a_{2_3}&1&\dots&a_{3_n}\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
a_{1_n}&a_{2_n}&a_{3_n}&\dots&1
\end{array}
\right) \ \ , \ \ 
B=\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
1&b_{1_2}&b_{1_3}&\dots&b_{1_n}\\
b_{1_2}&1&b_{2,3}&\dots&b_{2_n}\\
b_{1_3}&b_{2_3}&1&\dots&b_{3_n}\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
b_{1_n}&b_{2_n}&b_{3_n}&\dots&1
\end{array}
\right)
$$

and show what $AB$ looks like but it started looking like such a mess that I'm absolutely positive there must be a more elegant way of doing it.

Basically I'm fresh out of ideas and I'd really appreciate some help on this because I've been stuck on it for about two days.

Cheers and thanks in advance :)

Comment: You want to show that $(AB)^t = AB$. You know that $(AB)^t = B^t A^t$ (that's true for any matrices), and then by symmetry, you know that $(AB)^t = B^t A^t = BA$. So you need to prove that under your conditions, $AB = BA$. Is that true or not? As Will suggests, writing out examples is likely to help.

Comment: In particular, you might want to look at the $(1, 3)$ entry for the $3 \times 3$ case.

Comment: Does this seem intuitively true to you? Honest question here, because it doesn’t to me. And because of that, my first instinct would be to try to _disprove_ it. And that can be done with just a single counterexample.

Comment: There's a deeper result, even: *any matrix can be expressed as a product of two symmetric matrices*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure of what you mean by $n$-ordered (but I interpret it as $A, B \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$), so I'm assuming that you have no other restrictions on your entries other than $a_{ii} = b_{ii} = 1$ for $i \in \{1, \ldots, n\}$.

Consider:

$$
A = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 0 \\
2 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and
$$
B = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 2 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
2 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Then
$$
AB =
\begin{bmatrix}      
1 &    2  &   2 \\
2 &    1  &   4 \\
2 &    0  &   1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
is not symmetric.

I came up with this example by trying to find two symmetric matrices $A$ and $B$ that were not strictly (row) diagonally dominant (i.e., not positive definite). I'll go through later and try to add why this might work, but for now I feel that I got lucky.

Comment: Wow, you're right... Thank you so much!!