# Given $A,B$ symmetric positive definite matrices, is $B^{-1}A$ always symmetric positive definite?

Tags: matrices, positive-definite, symmetric-matrices

Given $A$ and $B$ to be symmetric positive definite matrices. Is the product $B^{-1}A$ always positive definite and symmetric?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is the product of symmetric positive semidefinite matrices positive definite?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/113842/is-the-product-of-symmetric-positive-semidefinite-matrices-positive-definite)

Comment: @eminem I am wondering if it is symmetric as well.

Comment: Product of two symmetric matrices may not be symmetric. https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2520846/598858

Comment: Have a look at this one 
https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2001516/316749 
, and note that $A$ and $B$ commute iff $A$ and $B^{-1}$ commute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No for symmetry. Symmetry is not true because:

$(B^{-1} A)^T = A^T B^{{-1}^T} = A B^{T^{-1}} = A B^{-1}$

The above only equals the original equation if $A$ and $B^{-1}$ are commutative, which isn't an inherent property of positive definite matrices. The only case I know of in which they are commutative is when they can both be diagonalized and they have the same eigenvector basis. Only the first one is guaranteed for these matrices as symmetric implies diagonalizable.

Further evidence: [https://math.vanderbilt.edu/sapirmv/msapir/jan22.html#:~:text=If%20the%20product%20of%20two,BA%20then%20AB%20is%20symmetric](https://math.vanderbilt.edu/sapirmv/msapir/jan22.html#:%7E:text=If%20the%20product%20of%20two,BA%20then%20AB%20is%20symmetric).

A question that should address the eigenvalue part: [Is the product of symmetric positive semidefinite matrices positive definite?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/113842/is-the-product-of-symmetric-positive-semidefinite-matrices-positive-definite)

Comment: Good point. I meant in general for commutative matrices but will edit